# CSS scroll not showing properly on mobile device

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile, html

I have the code at the bottom of this post controlling a `<div>` within my page `<div>` in jQuery Mobile. I have this div to make a table scroll, as it overflows horizontally on the page. It shows up as in this screenshot, however:

[image: Table fills ~50% of the page, then scrolls]

This same issue occurs when it is oriented vertically, but this view illustrates it better. I have scrolled the div sideways as well to better illustrate the two borders. I want the div to simply fill the full width of the page on mobile devices, as it displays properly on larger screens, but I want it to scroll horizontally if it overflows. I have tried both `overflow: scroll;` and `overflow: auto;` in addition to trying the code with and without `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. No method that I have tried for setting the width has yet worked, including `width: 100%;` and `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;` as suggested elsewhere.

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px){
    .ui-page {
    width: 960px !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
        border-right: 5px #111111 outset !important;
        border-left: 5px #111111 outset !important;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .tblscroll {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```

Simplified HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="resultsmain" data-title="Survey Results">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Title</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">text
        <div class="tblscroll">
            <table>
                ...table information...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post some code the page structure.

Comment: @Omar I've updated it, sorry.

Comment: It's okay. in your case, I recommend using `ui-grid`. check this http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-grids.html

Answer (score 1):

you could try using a CSS display block around your div elements width defined width's and adjusting the percentages.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though its the table itself which is the issue.

I would set the table width to 100%, and fix rows that won't grow or shrink

> table{ width:100%; }

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. I tried using both the CSS and HTML methods of setting `width` to `100%`, but neither fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really help at all, but I loaded it up today and it works perfectly. I changed nothing from yesterday to today, so it must have been a caching issue of some sort (even though I had cleared my mobile cache).